# Normal force at junction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Question is to compare normal forces  at A,B and C. I found out theta subtended by arc AB to be $30°$. Problem is at point B. As for a point just before B, normal force is $mg\cos30° + mv^2/100$. But for a point just after B normal force is $mg\cos30° - mv^2/200$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Excuse me, I have particular problem pointed. I did my work ,if you carefully read my question I just want to know what happens at point B.

Comment: This is not a worked example question and it's solution is not given. Even my teacher is confused in this question. Hoped to get answer here

Comment: I think , you can't apply the centripetal force at the junction. The normal force will be just $mg cos\theta$ where $tan\theta$ is slope at the junction.

Comment: Thats my problem, let function be x^3. Then curvature changes at x=0 . So maybe we can't define centripetal force there